# Bokeh plotting: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'line'

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I've just installed the latest version of Anaconda.

I am having a basic problem with Bokeh, from this [example](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/gallery/correlation.html).

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
f = figure()
f.line(x, y)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'line'
```

I can plot by saying line(x,y), but it looks like the above method would provide more flexibility if it worked.

Comment: Same thing here with bokeh 0.6.1 on OS X: `figure()` returns `None`, which explains the observed behavior.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The example (and even the [user guide](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/plotting.html#at-a-glance)) contradict the [documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=figure#bokeh.plotting.figure) for `bokeh.plotting.figure()`, which  explicitly says it returns `None`, which explains the error you observe.

Using `line()` directly therefore seems to be the way to go.

However, this holds for bokeh versions before 0.7: [version 0.7 deprecated implicit plotting](http://continuum.io/blog/bokeh-0.7). This means that `figure().line()` should work with bokeh 0.7+. The documentation for `figure()` has apparently not yet been updated.

Comment: Great. I updated to version 0.7 and it works now. I had incorrectly assumed that updating anaconda would bring my Bokeh up-to-date.

Comment: Just FYI the User Guide and reference has since been updated.